# Jquery tooltip position in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm trying to add tooltips with jQueryUI in my Worpress site.
They are displayed, but it seems that the position parameter is ignored.
Tooltips always appear at top center of the target element, no matter what I set as position.

```
$('.my-tooltip').tooltip({
    position: { my: "right top", at: "left bottom" }
});
```

jQuery UI core, position and tooltip are loaded.
Any idea why?

Thanks!

Edit: Actually, none of the tooltip options are working...
This will not work, and the defaut title attribute will be displayed:

```
$('.my-tooltip').tooltip({
    content: "test"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually bootstrap has his own tooltip function which overrides jQuery's.
Then one must use [boostrap parameters](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-options), such as:

```
$('.my-tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: "bottom"
});
```